# Extending typescript classes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oop

Let's say I have a base class:

```
class BaseClass {
  public id: string;
  public value: string;
  public label: string;
  public createdAt: string;
  public updatedAt: string;
  constructor(apiResponse: any) {
    this.id = apiResponse.id;
    this.value = apiResponse.value;
    this.label = apiResponse.label;
    this.createdAt = apiResponse.created_at;
    this.updatedAt = apiResponse.updated_at;
  }
}
```

That I am extending:

```
class FirstExtension extends BaseClass {
  constructor(responseObject: any) {
    super(responseObject); 
  }
}
```

and:

```
class SecondExtension extends BaseClass {
  constructor(responseObject: any) {
    super(responseObject); 
  }
```

I want to use this in a generic component in react with typescript. which no trouble so far, but I want the FirstExtension class not to have access to the "label" property, and the SecondExtension to have access to it, I could achieve this by adding "protected label" in the declaration of BaseClass and filling it in the SecondExtension declaraction:

```
class SecondExtension extends BaseClass {
  label: string;
  constuctor(responseObject: any) {
    super(responseObject); 
    this.label = responseObject.label;
  }
```

the issue is when creating a component takes a prop of type BaseClass, that could be either FirstExtension of SecondExtension, or other classes implementing BaseClass, I can't access the label property, because it is protected and not all extensions of BaseClas can access it.
So what is the best solution for implementing something similar to this?

this is the generic component:

```
   type ComponentProps = {
     resource?: BaseClass | null,
     onCreate: (resource: BaseClass) => void,
     onEdit: (resource: BaseClass) => void,
     isEditing: boolean,
     hasLabel?: boolean
     isLoading?: boolean,
   }
   
const GenericComponent = ({ resource, onCreate: onCreate, onEdit, isEditing, hasLabel = false, isLoading = false }: ComponentProps) => {
   const [name, setName] = useState(resource?.value || "")
   const [nameError, setNameError] = useState<string | null>(null)
   const [label, setLabel] = useState(resource?.label || "")

   return <></>
 }
```

in the GenericComponent: when creating the state to the label I get this error

> Property 'label' is protected and only accessible within class 'BaseClass' and its subclasses.

I am looking for the best practice, because I have around 9 extensions of the base class, that all should use the same exact component but some have access to different properties than others.

Comment: you can use `instanceof` or `'label' in yourObject`

Comment: @Sasix can you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please make sure your code here is a [mre] without unrelated problems like typographical errors (e.g., "`constuctor`" is misspelled).  Also, if you're having an issue it would be nice for your code to demonstrate it... the "I can't access the label property, because it is protected and not all extensions of BaseClas can access it." part would be nice to see as code so we don't have to guess what might be happening

Comment: @jcalz sure let me edit my question

Comment: I wouldn't use classes for this at all... I would have the data types be plain objects and use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) or some other form of [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types) to figure out which variant I have in the component.

Comment: Maybe you just want `label` to be *optional* in the base class and then narrow to either `string` or `undefined` in subclasses like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbv6Bm)?    If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?